# $lookup ObjectId in an array of ObjectId mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, lookup

So basically I have a Patient schema, in which there are 2 fields:

```
patientSchema = {
  //other_fields

  current_facility: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Facility",
  },

  close_contact_list: {
    type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    ref: "Patient",
  }
}
```

If i populate like this

```
Patient.find().populate({
        path: "close_contact_list",
        populate: {
          path: "current_facility",
          model: "Facility",
        },
        select: "id_number name dob status current_facility",
      })
```

The result of 1 document would be:

```
{
   //other_fields
   "close_contact_list": [
            {
                "_id": "62e7e80bcdde7f149602775e",
                "id_number": "201260388",
                "name": "Tom",
                "dob": "2003-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "status": "F1",
                "current_facility": {
                    "location": {
                        "formattedAddress": "Phuong Phường 2, Quan Quận 2, TP Hồ Chí Minh",
                        "province": "Hồ Chí Minh",
                        "district": "Quận 2",
                        "ward": "Phường 2"
                    },
                    "_id": "62e7d60596997310f14e4bdb",
                    "name": "Thu Duc",
                    "capacity": 3000,
                    "current_count": 2,
                    "__v": 0
                }
            },
            {
                //similar_to_above
            },
            ...
    ]
}
```

My question is how can i do the same thing but by using aggregate. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Patient.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Facility",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "current_facility",
      "as": "current_facility"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "id_number": 1,
      "name": 1,
      "dob": 1,
      "status": 1,
      "current_facility": 1
    }
  }
])
```